# How to group files in a list based on name?

Tags: r, group-by, split, filenames, python-itertools

I have 4 files:

```
MCD18A1.A2001001.h15v05.061.2020097222704.hdf

MCD18A1.A2001001.h16v05.061.2020097221515.hdf

MCD18A1.A2001002.h15v05.061.2020079205554.hdf

MCD18A1.A2001002.h16v05.061.2020079205717.hdf
```

And I want to group them by name (date: A2001001 and A2001002) inside a list, something like this:

```
[[MCD18A1.A2001001.h15v05.061.2020097222704.hdf, MCD18A1.A2001001.h16v05.061.2020097221515.hdf], [MCD18A1.A2001002.h15v05.061.2020079205554.hdf, MCD18A1.A2001002.h16v05.061.2020079205717.hdf]]
```

I did this using Python, but I don't know how to do with R:

```
# Seperate files by date
MODIS_files_bydate = [list(i) for _, i in itertools.groupby(MODIS_files, lambda x: x.split('.')[1])]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
g <- sub("^[^\\.]*\\.([^\\.]+)\\..*$", "\\1", s)
split(s, g)
#$A2001001
#[1] "MCD18A1.A2001001.h15v05.061.2020097222704.hdf"
#[2] "MCD18A1.A2001001.h16v05.061.2020097221515.hdf"
#
#$A2001002
#[1] "MCD18A1.A2001002.h15v05.061.2020079205554.hdf"
#[2] "MCD18A1.A2001002.h16v05.061.2020079205717.hdf"
```

---

### regex explained

The regex is divided in three parts.

1. `^[^\\.]*\\.`

   - `^` first circumflex marks the beginning of the string;
   - `^[^\\.]` at the beginning, a class negating a dot (the second `^`). The dot is a meta-character and, therefore, must be escaped, `\\.`;
   - the sequence with no dots at the beginning repeated zero or more times (`*`);
   - the previous sequence ends with a dot, `\\.`.
2. `([^\\.]+)` is a capture group.

   - `[^\\.]` the class with no dots, like above;
   - `[^\\.]+` repeated at least one time (`+`).
3. `\\..*$"`

   - `\\.` starting with one dot
   - `\\..*$` any character repeated zero or more times until the end (`$`).

What `sub` is replacing is the capture group, what is between parenthesis, by itself, `\\1`. This discards everything else.

---

### Data

```
s <- "
MCD18A1.A2001001.h15v05.061.2020097222704.hdf
MCD18A1.A2001001.h16v05.061.2020097221515.hdf
MCD18A1.A2001002.h15v05.061.2020079205554.hdf
MCD18A1.A2001002.h16v05.061.2020079205717.hdf"
s <- scan(text = s, what = character())
```

Comment: This work! But I don't understand very well the g because of the regex, can you explain what sub is replacing? Thank you

Comment: @Just_4n0th3r_Pr0gr4mm3r Added the explanation. See now.

Answer (score 1):

How would you like the outcome organized?

This is a solution:

```
files <- c("MCD18A1.A2001001.h15v05.061.2020097222704.hdf",
           
           "MCD18A1.A2001001.h16v05.061.2020097221515.hdf",
           
           "MCD18A1.A2001002.h15v05.061.2020079205554.hdf",
           
           "MCD18A1.A2001002.h16v05.061.2020079205717.hdf")

unique_date <- unique(sub("^[^\\.]*\\.([^\\.]+)\\..*$", "\\1", files))
# (credit to Rui Barradas for the nice regular expression)

grouped_files <- lapply(unique_date, function(x){files[grepl(x, files)]})

names(grouped_files) <- unique_date

> grouped_files
# $A2001001
# [1] "MCD18A1.A2001001.h15v05.061.2020097222704.hdf"  "MCD18A1.A2001001.h16v05.061.2020097221515.hdf"

# $A2001002
# [1] "MCD18A1.A2001002.h15v05.061.2020079205554.hdf"  "MCD18A1.A2001002.h16v05.061.2020079205717.hdf"
```

Comment: Why do you apply the unique function? Can you explain what sub is replacing? Thank you

Comment: So that there will be a "group" for each date. Then all relevant dates are found for each group. 
sub() is just one way to pick out the dates: the first argument being the pattern (what's between the first two dots), and the second argument references that pattern and is the replacement. Each filename is replaced with the found pattern.